# Samba - persmission denied problem

Tags: samba

Oracle Virtual Box Debian. I'm trying to do a samba share like this:

```
[share]
comment = test
path = /home/share
browseable = yes
writeable = yes
read only = no
```

Then I go to Browse Network -> MyPc -> [share] and try to create anything. I'm getting the "Persmission denied" error. Samba user was created. Home options = read only = no, browseable = yes, create and directory mask = 777. Also I tried to do follow symlinks / wide links and those 2 weren't working too.
Tried to do it outside home too, still nothing. Don't know what to do there. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to state 'security = share' in the [global] paragraph if you want to share it with everyone. I just don't find the page I got that from, sorry.

EDIT:
Here it is: https://serverfault.com/questions/470650/samba-configuration-for-public-shares#494861